# How to soften/smooth mesh curves?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I created mesh from a curve and I want now soften the curved parts of it like this selection.

[image]

I subdivided this part and moved vertices manually to get this:
[image]

But I'm sure there is some better way to do this.
Basically I want to make a flat road but i don't want to have million unnecessary vertices on straight parts.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the "Loop Tools" addon will fix this without having to redo it as most other responses are suggesting.

Answer (score 10):

You probably don't need all those subdivisions on the edges that run across the curve:

[image]

[image]

---

Aside from that, there are several ways you could go about doing this:

## Spin

You could use the *spin* tool (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>):

1. Position the 3D cursor (<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>)
2. Spin (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)

[image]

## Subdivide

Subdividing can work well if you only subdivide the edges that follow around the curve:

[image]

*Unfortunately subdivide smooth doesn't seem to work in this case, so you'll still need to move the vertices manually.*

## Curves

You could also use a curve, then convert it to a mesh later with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

1. Add a curve
2. Add a straight curve as a bevel object
3. Extrude curve (<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>)

[image]

---

You should also be able to use *bevel*, but currently there seems to be a bug with beveling 2D planes in 2.72..

Comment: up voted just for the gif of the curve process.

Comment: Thanks for useful tips. I want to stick with Bezier curves but is there an option to automatically adjust resolution according to its sharpness. Right now its resolution is set per segment so I can create shorter segments for more complex parts but i just want to have single segment for completely straight parts. If no, what is the fastest way to remove unwanted segments - currently doing  shift-clicking on each edge and hit delete>limited dissolve.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos You could use a *decimate* modifier set to *planar*, or you could make the straight segments of the curve vector by selecting the end control vertices and pressing `V` *> Vector*

Answer (score 0):

Start with a clean mesh like gandalf3 shows, with no inner edges:

[image]

Step 1: Create a second row of edges along the rim using the edge loop tool.

[image]

Use the subdivision surface modifier:

Modifiers -> Subdivision Surface -> Catmull Clark

[image]

If needed, you can adjust the position of the edges in edit mode before applying it.

Comment: ...I just realized how old that question is :P